# Material appearing as bright white or white on some objects while using Eevee Render in 2.8

Tags: materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I have a scene with 7 different materials and 405 objects. One of the materials is displayed as I want it to for some object, while other objects it is applied to behave either like a bright white emission shader or a dark black diffuse. The material uses the Diffuse BSDF shader only a with normal map, a red diffuse color and a value of 1 for roughness. Using the cycles render in

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about issues with unfinished experimental development software

Answer (score 2):

Alright I realized the issue is that I only UV unwrapped some of the objects. I thought I could save time by only unwrapping the larger objects. I hope this behaves more similarly to the Cycles render in the future.